# How to pass Authorization: Bearer {{tokenObtidoNoEndpointDeLogin} using Python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, authorization

Well, first, I had to make this to get a token:

```
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    data = '{\n "login": "alexa",\n "password": "e20d1c58"\n}'
    parameters = ['accessToken']
    
    response = requests.post('https://xxxxxxxxxxxx', headers=headers, data=data).json()
    response
    accessToken = response['accessToken']
```

Now, I'm trying to pass that `accessToken` that I obtained from the earlier code, but I don't know how.

I've tried this:

```
headers = {"Authorization": {accessToken}, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
userEncontrado = requests.put("xxxxxxxxx", headers=headers, json=data)
userEncontrado.json()
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Value for header {Authorization: {'J9T1eNDO-hS9pmdsT4_HKkwLBBXe9Urpp-7tUvFFVqZH2tcJrMXgUEqu7x2Sb5f6FFckZ6MqjqorZ-pWX4k_NUJTWp1b2_ZT8LKQBgcPStd1_toDcxfNgY6ftmVuupwdAfH1zi1IdAmAIeM-6651C3CN3612mioy6M9Aa_hQE9oxdg_1j6YSPwWfAtWUqbXPqzBWT5MDig_GhOQXNn5iPLymBEU'}} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'set'>

Can anyone help me?

The HTTP is:

```
GET xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/?cpf={{cpf}} HTTP/1.1 
Host: xxxxxxx.com.br

Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer {{tokenObtidoNoEndpointDeLogin}}
```

Comment: `"Authorization": f"Bearer {accessToken}"`

Answer (score 0):

{} creates a set in python.

you can use an f-string so it's an actual string you're posting.

```
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {accessToken}", 'Content-Type':'application/json'
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting this. I think it is an API created by API Gateway: {'message': "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=xxxxxxxx"}

Comment: The code I gave solves the previous issue you had as you were trying to post a set


"must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'set'>"

Comment: can you accept my answer as the answer then please. cheers @ThaisLino